# Optional join with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a situation when I have to load data from several table into a single object, i.e. I have separate tables for `BasicProperties` and several kinds of "advanced" properties` (I'm not allowed to refactor either the database or the object model).

However, since loading the advanced properties is expensive, and unnecessary in most cases, I want to omit it, unless explicitly specified.

What I currently have is something like:

```
  from basics in ctx.Basics
    join numerics in ctx.Numerics on basics.ID equals numerics.ItemID
    join alphas in ctx.Alphas on basics.ID equals alphas.Itemid
    join cplx in ctx.Complex on basics.ID equals cplx.Itemid into complex
  select new HodgePodge
             {
               Basics = basics,
               Numerics = numerics,
               Alphas = alpha,
               Complex = complex
             };
```

so I need some (easy) way to include / exclude the loading of the `Numerics`, `Alphas` and `Complex` database tables.

Basically, I'm a "guest" on this project trying to optimize the loading code, so I'm not allowed to change the code too much, and the worst-case performance must stay at least the same.

Comment: You should have navigation properties defined (unless some of those joins are to views, it's not always possible then), which would take care of that via lazy loading - you'd actually have to explicitly load related entities.

Comment: Why don't you build your query dynamically based on your condition? (e.g. Include join in case advancePropertiesRequired). Or just have two queries one for each side of the condition.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek, no, no navigation properties on the type (`HodgePodge`) that I need to load (and can't add them)

Comment: @AdolfoPerez - I have 3 optionals in the example, so that would require 8 different queries (and the real case has about a dozen optionals) :)

Comment: @SWeko Navigation properties should be on `Basics`, attached to a context. Otherwise you'll have to prepare a method to 'manually' add join when needed.

Comment: @SWeko, you can actually load each of the optionals independently. That will still require separate `if` for each optional though

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek - No, Basics is not connected to any of the other properties by navigation properties (and I can't change that)

Comment: @Andrei, I was thinking along those lines. The only downside is that would increase the number of database roundtrips.

Comment: I think you missed the first two `into` statements, or maybe you are just missing `alpha`

Comment: @Aducci, no, Numerics and Alphas have a 1:1 relationship with Basics, and Complex has a 1:m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your `join` logic into the `select` statement, and based on your relationship type (`1:1, 1:*`) you use `FirstOrDefault` or `Where`

```
bool loadNumerics = true;
bool loadAlphas  = true;
bool loadComplex = true;

var query = from basics in ctx.Basics
            select new HodgePodge
            {
               Basics = basics,
               Numerics = ctx.Numerics.FirstOrDefault(x => loadNumerics == true && basics.ID == x.ItemID),
               Alphas = ctx.Alphas.FirstOrDefault(x => loadAlphas == true && basics.ID == x.Itemid),
               Complex = ctx.Complex.Where(x => loadComplex == true && basics.ID == x.Itemid),
            };
```

Comment: @WahidBitar, in his comments he stated the relationship type, `Numerics` and `Alphas` are 1:1 so I used `FirstOrDefault`, `Complex` is 1:*, so I used `Where`

Comment: It'll threw NotSupportedException "Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable .... Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Comment: @WahidBitar, Good catch, I added a Where clause to check if you want to load or not

Comment: +1 Perfect solution :) How I missed it ?! Thank you :)

Comment: This will still roundtrip the checks to the database, but it will speed up the query.

Comment: However because the `Numerics`, `Alphas` etc tables have literally hundreds of columns, I still end up with a bunch of `null`s wastefully transmitted .

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
IQueryable<HodgePodge> Query = ctx.Basics.Select(u => new HodgePodge(){ Basic = u }).AsQueryable();

        if(ConditionNumeric)
            Query = Query.Join(ctx.Numerics,
                q => q.Basic.ID,
                n => n.Itemid,
                (q, n) => new HodgePodge(){ Basic = q.Basic, Numeric = n })
            .AsQueryable();

        if(ConditionAlpha)
            Query = Query.Join(ctx.Alphas,
                q => q.Basic.ID,
                a => a.Itemid,
                (q, a) => new HodgePodge(){ Basic = q.Basic, Alpha = a })
            .AsQueryable();

        if(ConditionComplex)
            Query = Query.Join(ctx.Complex,
                q => q.Basic.ID,
                c => c.Itemid,
                (q, c) => new HodgePodge(){ Basic = q.Basic, Complex = c })
            .AsQueryable();

        return Query.ToList();
```

Comment: Tnx for the response, it's nice, albeit a bit wordy :)
Also, I would need to include all previous things in the query, in case all of the conditions are true.